# I created a formula field which gives the percentage and when i place the field at the group level the same value gets repeated for each group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Here is the sample data

```
column
Yes
Yes 
No 
No
```

I need to show the percentage of this column at the group level

I have 5 groups and each group may have different values in the column.

I created formula field which shows the percentage:

```
if column = 'yes' 
then 1 
else 0

if column = 'No' 
then 1 
else 0
```

then summed it up and calculated the percentages in the formula field but when I place the formula field on the group each group shows the total percentage but not at the group level

Comment: what is the percentage formula you used for all groups.. cna you post?

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect place to use a **running total** with a conditional evaluation

Step 1. To create the numerator,

1. Create a running total (Field Explorer, right click Running Total and click New)
2. On the Field to summarize, add the column and select 'Count'
3. Under Evaluate, click use a formula", click the formula icon enter this logic 
   `{Command.column1} = 'yes'`
4. Under the Reset section, click "on change of group" and select the group you want.

[image]

Click OK; then drag this running total to the group footer of the group you selected. This will give you the raw number of times this column equals "yes" within that group.

Step2. To create the denominator, we will create **another running total** which counts the column (yes and no)

1. Create a running total named "RT_ColumnTotal"
2. Add the same column, select Count
3. Under Evaluate, select "for each record"
4. under Reset, select the group

[image]

Step3. Create a formula to divide the numerator by the denominator; enter this code `if {#RT_ColumnYes} > 0 then {#RT_ColumnYes}/{#RT_ColumnTotal} *100
else 0` -- This formula checks whether the RunningTotal for "Yes" is greater than 0, if so, divide against the RunningTotal for the column and multiply by 100. If Numerator is 0, then display 0

it should look like this
[image]